# Solving Killing equations using Mathematica

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, physics

I am trying to solve the Killing equation for a given metric, I am following the code shown in [Solving Killing equations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32843/solving-killing-equations), and here is my code

```
     xIN = {t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]};
        n = 4;
        met = {{1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, (-b^2 - r^2 - a^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2)/(
            a^2 + b^2 + r^2), 0, 0}, {0, 0, -b^2 - r^2 - a^2 Cos[\[Theta]]^2, 
            0}, {0, 0, 0, (-a^2 - b^2 - r^2) Sin[\[Theta]]^2}};
        
        inversemetric := Inverse[met] // FullSimplify
        coord = xIN;
        
        (*Christoffel symbols*)
        
        affine := 
         affine = 
          Simplify[
           Table[(1/2) Sum[
              inversemetric[[\[Mu], \[Rho]]] (D[met[[\[Rho], \[Nu]]], 
                  coord[[\[Lambda]]]] + 
                 D[met[[\[Rho], \[Lambda]]], coord[[\[Nu]]]] - 
                 D[met[[\[Nu], \[Lambda]]], coord[[\[Mu]]]]), {\[Rho], 1, 
               n}], {\[Nu], 1, n}, {\[Lambda], 1, n}, {\[Mu], 1, n}]]
        
        listaffine := 
          Table[{Style[
              Subsuperscript[\[CapitalGamma], 
               Row[{coord[[\[Nu]]], coord[[\[Lambda]]]}], coord[[\[Mu]]]], 
              18], Style[affine[[\[Lambda], \[Nu], \[Mu]]], 14]}, {\[Lambda], 
             1, n}, {\[Nu], 1, n}, {\[Mu], 1, n}] // FullSimplify;
        
        data = {#[[1]], "=", #[[2]], #[[3]], "=", #[[4]]} & /@ 
           Partition[DeleteCases[Flatten[listaffine], Null], 4];
        
        data = Insert[data[[#]], #, 1] & /@ Range[Length[data]];
        TableForm[data]
        
        (*Derivations*)
        
        der[f_, \[Sigma]_] := D[f, xIN[[\[Sigma]]]]
        
        derxU[xU_, \[Mu]_, \[Nu]_] := 
         Module[{\[Lambda]}, 
           der[xU[[\[Mu]]], \[Nu]] + 
            Sum[affine[[\[Nu], \[Mu], \[Lambda]]] xU[[\[Lambda]]], {\[Lambda],
               1, n}]] // FullSimplify
        
        derxd[xd_, \[Mu]_, \[Nu]_] := 
         Module[{\[Lambda]}, 
           der[xd[[\[Mu]]], \[Nu]] - 
            Sum[affine[[\[Nu], \[Lambda], \[Mu]]] xd[[\[Lambda]]], {\[Lambda],
               1, n}]] // FullSimplify
        
        derxUup[xU_, \[Mu]_, \[Nu]_] := 
         Module[{\[Lambda], \[Rho]}, 
           Sum[inversemetric[[\[Nu], \[Rho]]] (der[xU[[\[Mu]]], \[Rho]] + 
               Sum[affine[[\[Rho], \[Mu], \[Lambda]]] xU[[\[Lambda]]], {\
        \[Lambda], 1, 4}]), {\[Rho], 1, 4}]] // FullSimplify
        
        derxdup[xd_, \[Mu]_, \[Nu]_] := 
         Module[{\[Lambda], \[Rho]}, 
           Sum[inversemetric[[\[Nu], \[Rho]]] (der[xd[[\[Mu]]], \[Rho]] - 
               Sum[affine[[\[Rho], \[Lambda], \[Mu]]] xd[[\[Lambda]]], {\
        \[Lambda], 1, 4}]), {\[Rho], 1, 4}]] // FullSimplify

        \[Xi] = {\[Xi]t[t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Xi]r[t, 
    r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Xi]\[Theta][t, 
    r, \[Theta], \[Phi]], \[Xi]\[Phi][t, r, \[Theta], \[Phi]]};

Killeq = 
 Table[derxd[\[Xi], \[Nu], \[Mu]] + derxd[\[Xi], \[Mu], \[Nu]] == 
    0, {\[Mu], 1, n}, {\[Nu], 1, n}] // Flatten
```

Then I got the following coupled PDE which couldn't output the expected result using Dsolve
[image].

There is one answer about the Cartan-Kuranishi approach but I searched this method and didn't find too many resources about it, so I wonder is there any way to solve this equation more directly? Is there a general way to solve this type of coupled PDE using Mathematica?